# Installing Xcode with iOS 4.3 device simulator?

Tags: install, mac-appstore, xcode, ios

I installed Xcode 4.3.1 two days ago. I need to access the iOS 4.3 device simulator, but it is not available in the new Xcode. So I went to Xcode > Preferences > Download (tab) and downloaded the Xcode 4.3.1 developer library and the iOS 5.1 library, hoping I could add the 4.3 simulator.

But, this hasn't worked. So far I haven't got the 4.3 simulator installed on my Xcode. What is the solution for this?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/43309/4408

Comment: Well in mine, when i click on downloads, it doesn;t show iOS 4.3 Stimulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option to download iOS 4.3 simulator is available from within Xcode. You can find it under `Preferences > Downloads`. Just click on `"Install"` and you might have to enter your Apple ID credentials.

[image]

If you don't see this option, you could try removing your older versions of Xcode and installing the latest one from the Appstore. My version is 4.3.2.

Comment: I have xcode 4.3.1. Do you want me to uninstall it ?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Simulator app can be found here if it’s installed correctly:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
```

Or here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app
```

Try a Spotlight search for “Simulator” to make sure the installation actually failed, before you try anything else.

Comment: How can i navigate to the above paths. I tried spotlight but i was unable to find Simulator there

Comment: Open Terminal.app and enter `open /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications; open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications`.

Answer (score 0):

In the iPhone Simulator, select required iOS version (4.3.2) from Hardware > Version menu.

Comment: In Hardware-->Version there's only 5.1 (98176). I need 4.3 :S

Comment: Try upgrading Xcode to 4.3.2 and check Preferences->Downloads again